# .accdb file weird behavior of connection string

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am new to C# development but this behavior of .accdb database file is just weird:

This is my current connection string, as my .accdb file located in new directory:

```
string connectString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
                + "Data Source=C:\\Users\\testAcc\\Desktop\\TJ\\26-05-2014\\aa\\test.accdb";
```

It shows  *'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\25-05-2014\Anviz\test.accdb' not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.*

My debugger shows this path:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\25-05-2014\\Anviz\\test.accdb"
```

Why? I changes the connection string then where the old connection string comes from??

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to connect to MS Access from C@ or other way round? Where do you see your connection string? How did you connect to MS Access DB?

Comment: What object is getting this connection string? where is it set? is it set in the designer and code possibly? And your seeing the discrepancy?

Comment: I just solved it. By deleting the program debug database. BTW thanks AlexanderGalkin and Brad.